# Relation between slit width and intensity of light in Young's double slit experiment

Tags: interference

In some places , it says slit width is directly proportional to intensity while in other places intensity is directly proportional to (slit width)² .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the width of a slit related to the intensity of light passing through it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102134/how-is-the-width-of-a-slit-related-to-the-intensity-of-light-passing-through-it)

Comment: In this link also , some are saying directly proportional to it and some saying directly proportional to the square of it.

Comment: Are you sure that the situation isn't some sources saying the field strength is proprtional to the slit width and other sources are saying the intensity is proportional to the square of the slit width? Can you site a specific source that says the intensity is proportional to the slit width?

Comment: The link in first comment , the first reply there says intensity is propitiational to slit width and book by Mcgraw Hill.